# how to add new array in JSON using PHP with this format?

Tags: php, json

I spent few hours, until end up seeking help. I'm new in JSON and PHP, anyone can help or guide me for this format im working. Any attention are very appreciated.

This is the JSON tree structure im expecting

```
{
"table-name": "Beta",
"created-on": "May 03, 2021",
"token": "6kh3o0oRLZreJ9K",
"columns": "Name,Org,Address,Mobile,Email,Pass",
"data": [
    {
        "Name": "Anthony ",
        "Org": "Byahe",
        "Address": "San Pedro",
        "Mobile": "425",
        "Email": "testacc@gmail.com",
        "Pass": "01212125134"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Bev",
        "Org": "Hnono",
        "Address": "Palawan",
        "Mobile": "24525",
        "Email": "s4aww@gmail.com",
        "Pass": "0000"
    }
]}
```

I'm pulling this JSON on my files

```
$jsn = file_get_contents('./tables/test.json');
$arr = json_decode($jsn);
```

And here my work on PHP, on trying to add new array using array_push

```
 $array = Array(
"table-name"=>"Beta",
"created-on"=>"May 03, 2021",
"token"=>"6kh3o0oRLZreJ9K",
"columns"=>"Name,Org,Address,Mobile,Email,Pass",

//Array(
 "data" => array(
    array (
    "Name" => $_POST["fullname"],
    "Org" => $_POST["organization"],
    "Address" => $_POST["address"],
    "Mobile" => $_POST["phone"],
    "Email" => $_POST["email"],
    "Pass" => $_POST["password"]
 ),
),

);

  array_push();
 $json = json_encode($array);

 if (file_put_contents("./tables/test.json", $json))
 echo "Account created successfully...";
 else 
 echo "Unable to create an account...";
```

Comment: It's not clear how you're trying to add that information to the original array. Can you please show the code that actually performs the push?

Comment: I'm sorry, Im very new to this, and still learning how to use this stack overflow. I'll try to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data field is array of objects? If yes, try something like this...

```
$array = [
    "table-name"=>"Beta",
    "created-on"=>"May 03, 2021",
    "token"=>"6kh3o0oRLZreJ9K",
    "columns"=>"Name,Org,Address,Mobile,Email,Pass",
    "data" => []
]

$data = [
    "Name" => $_POST["fullname"],
    "Org" => $_POST["organization"],
    "Address" => $_POST["address"],
    "Mobile" => $_POST["phone"],
    "Email" => $_POST["email"],
    "Pass" => $_POST["password"]
];

array_push($array["data"], $data);
$json = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Hi there, I'll edit my question, please review if you have a spare time, thanks for the attention, hope it can clear everything..Yes it was like im adding new items, it's a signup account using JSON and PHP

Comment: I have changed my answer. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add a new item to the "data" object.

You first json decode it, and add it to the array in php. Then you encode it again.

```
$json = '{
    "table-name": "Beta",
    "created-on": "May 03, 2021",
    "token": "6kh3o0oRLZreJ9K",
    "columns": "Name,Org,Address,Mobile,Email,Pass",
    "data": [
        {
            "Name": "Anthony ",
            "Org": "Byahe",
            "Address": "San Pedro",
            "Mobile": "425",
            "Email": "testacc@gmail.com",
            "Pass": "01212125134"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Bev",
            "Org": "Hnono",
            "Address": "Palawan",
            "Mobile": "24525",
            "Email": "s4aww@gmail.com",
            "Pass": "0000"
        }
    ]}';

$items = json_decode($json);

$items->data[] = [
    "Name" => $_POST["fullname"],
    "Org" => $_POST["organization"],
    "Address" => $_POST["address"],
    "Mobile" => $_POST["phone"],
    "Email" => $_POST["email"],
    "Pass" => $_POST["password"]];

echo json_encode($items);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the attention, this one looks so close, as I also test it, it's working. Yes. My goal is to add new item to the "data" object as it was a mini create account database project im working on JSON and PHP, but can you enlighten me some code how to inserting the variable "items" using array_push?